# How is the Dirac field classical before second quantization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, second-quantization

Maybe this is why I can't seem to understand the first thing about QFT.  [In the article on second quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization#Comment_on_nomenclature), they say that the name shouldn't really be "second quantization", because:

> One is not quantizing "again", as the term "second" might suggest; the field that is being quantized is not a Schrödinger wave function that was produced as the result of quantizing a particle, but is a classical field (such as the electromagnetic field or Dirac spinor field), essentially an assembly of coupled oscillators, that was not previously quantized.

WHAT??? I thought the Dirac equation was just the relativistic Schrodinger equation, albeit with the added benefit of spin and relativistic corrections.  It still gives discrete energy states, involves complex numbers, etc. etc.  Whereas, or so I thought, a classical field is something where you can directly measure the value at any point, like you can measure the electric/magnetic field by putting a stationary/moving charge there.

So this must be why the QFT wavefunction is now a *functional* of Dirac+EM field configurations, right?  But I'm still missing that key conceptual link: how does a given Dirac configuration correspond to a single physical reality (such that it is amenable to quantization!), and not a probability distribution like the Schrodinger wavefunction?  How do you measure the Dirac field?  Or if you can't, then why doesn't that matter, and how do the structures of QFT connect to experiment?

Comment: "*I thought...*" but now you know better :-) (FWIW: discreteness, complex numbers, etc. etc. are not necessarily indicative of a [theory being quantum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397694/84967)!).

Comment: There are a lot of questions here, but to answer what looks like your first misconception: The single particle Dirac equation, as originally presented by Dirac, is really a (somewhat pathological) limit of the Dirac QFT. It's really best to work with QFT from the outset where we are quantizing a classical field theory, before trying to understand the complications of how fixed-particle QM emerges from it in particular limits.

Comment: I agree. To say that the Dirac wave function is a classical field but the Schrödinger wave function is not, does not make sense. The distinction is artificial.

Comment: There's an extra complication that the classical Dirac field theory is sick. In some sense, because quantum mechanics is more fundamental, talking about deriving a quantum theory from a classical one is somewhat silly, but that's how the founders of quantum mechanics had to work (and it is useful in pedagogy), so we use that terminology.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt The statement that 'the classical Dirac field theory is sick' needs some clarification.

Comment: @my2cts If you start with the free Dirac Lagrangian, interpreting the spinors as having c-number components, the energy isn't bounded below so there's no stable ground state. I guess you can have the components be Grassmann numbers, but I don't know what such a theory means physically until one places it inside a (Berezin) path integral. But presumably there are some formally interesting aspects of these theories anyways.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Indeed, the Dirac Lagrangian has a multitude of problems, leading to desperate explanations such as Zitter Bewegung. The solutions of the Dirac equation, however, are correct.

Comment: Presumably the author means that the Dirac field doesn't result from the quantisation prescription of a point particle in the same way that wavefunctions do. Even though both are "classical fields" by the usual terminology.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt I think that derivation of quantum theory from classical should not be dismissed as a mere historical artifact: any quantum phenomena are acessible only via contact with *classical* objects (the measurement postulate). Also, the correspondence principle demands that the classical theory is contained in the quantum one as a limiting case.

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341389/difference-between-field-and-wavefunction).

Comment: @RogerVadim does a "pure quantum" derivation of QFT even exist?  Dont' they all start from a classical lagrangian, and then go through some procedure to produce a phemonology?  How does one do this without the classical Lagrangian/Hamiltonian?

Comment: I guess the whole question apart from the measurement part is susceptible to a clear answer. It's also my question how can one measure the value of a spinorial field at a certain point(for sure one can only measure the average over a spacial region). Without a double-slit-like experiment, it's impossible to measure the probability field.
Perhaps it's already what one does in the case of the EM field!

Comment: I don't buy the statement that since the potential is not measurable directly one should give up with the measurement idea, for one can definitely measure the Electric field and quantize the EM covariant tensor rather than the potential as one can "btw" observe that the Yang-Mills Lagrangians are written in terms of the field strength!

Comment: I guess the same problem appears in the case of an electric field intensity measurement too! 

Measurement of the strength of a single-mode field is quite impossible due to the phase-amplitude anticommutation unless there's a huge number of modes overlapping to build up a classically measurable field (correspondence principle). And a large number of modes means, a large number of "photons" which is pretty much similar to the case of spinorial field in which one needs a huge number of particles to measure the average probability at a certain region.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to put it in order, the fields are called **classical** not because they are directly measurable (electromagnetic vector potential is classical but not measurable, either) but because they are just (c-number) fields, like
$$
  \psi: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb C \qquad \text{or equivalently} \qquad \psi(x) \in \mathbb C \quad \text{for} \quad x \in \mathbb R^n,
$$
in opposite to **quantum** fields which are operator valued
$$
  \hat \psi(x): \mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F
$$
for every point $x \in \mathbb R^n$ in space where $\mathcal F$ is the Fock space in which they act.

In other words, classical (Schrödinger, Dirac) wavefunction $\psi$ is an element of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ itself, $\psi \in \mathcal H$, whereas a quantum (Schrödinger, Dirac) field $\hat \psi(x)$ is an operator in Fock space $\mathcal F$ (which is mathematically also a Hilbert space).

Regarding **first and second quantization**, in Hamiltonian mechanics one postulates the [Poisson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) for the position and momentum to become commutators of the position and momentum operators
$$
  \{q^i, p_j\} = \delta^i_j \qquad \rightarrow \qquad [Q^i, P_j] = i\, \hbar\, \delta^i_j
$$
while in field theory one postulates the [Poisson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) of the field and its canonical momentum to become the commutators of the field and its momentum operators
$$
  \{\phi(x), \pi(y)\} = \delta(x-y) \qquad \rightarrow \qquad [\Phi(x), \Pi(y)] = i\, \hbar\, \delta(x-y).
$$
In both cases one gets an algebra of operators and looks for its representations. In the first case it is the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, in the second the Fock space $\mathcal F$.
Elements of $\mathcal H$ are (Schrödinger, Dirac) **first quantized** wavefunctions $\psi$ which, treated as classical fields, are **second quantized** to become operators in Fock space $\mathcal F$.

I personally prefer the names *quantum mechanics* and *quantum field theory* as quantized versions of classical mechanics and classical field theory, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these wave equations - Maxwell, Schrödinger, Dirac, squared Dirac, Pauli, Klein-Gordon - are classical field equations. Their solutions are classical fields that behave like representations of the Poincaré group. It is the interpretation of these classical fields that makes the theory 'quantum'. For example, I interpret the electromagnetic potential as giving the expectation value of photon number, energy etc. This is how I deal with photon shot noise.

A quantum field is a linear combination of harmonic oscillator creation/annihilation operators, where the coefficients are taken from a wave function.

Answer (score -1):

I guess there's no wisdom(at least physical one!) in the answers given.
I don't care about the mathematical interpretation of a quantity to call it classical or quantum mechanical, but I'm pretty much sure that physics determines the difference between classical and quantum mechanical!

Answers like saying, quantum fields are operator-valued distributions and classical ones are c-numbers are merely arguments and don't mean anything physically meaningful!

Your question is quite wise due to its very honest standpoint and I have also an honest answer for it:

[Classical Hamiltonian equations for quantum systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)#Hamilton%27s_equations)

Here you can see how one can build a classical theory out of quantum mechanical Hamiltonian.

To me, this is precisely how one reaches a classical field theory for Dirac spinors!
You can choose your eigenbasis to be position or momentum or whatever you wish and then establish Dirac's lagrangian quite formally!

I guess everybody agrees that the complex root of a probability distribution is for sure a classical field since it assigns a number(complex or real or vector or etc) to every point of space. This is the very definition of a field.

This way one reaches a classical system with an infinite number of degrees of freedom("classical" oscillators attached to every point of space) that can be quantized in the following step(which means the oscillators(field values) will no longer be considered classical). It fills the gap between first and second quantization though I personally think one is always quantizing a classical system at each level, so there's no sense in saying on does a second quantization which has connotations like quantizing an already quantized system which is not the case!

No need for mathematics as far as there are simple physically meaningful interpretations :)